# How to enable design mode in flashbuilder

Tags: flash-builder, designmode

I am trying to enable the design mode on my trial flashbuilder but could not find any option to do so,

I have checked out Windows menu but there is no enable design mode, 
and Preferences but there is no Flex in preferences dialog to enable its design mode.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Te design mode is no longer supported by Flash builder versions greater than 4.6 .

and this is the reason :

"The Flash Builder design view was built as a SWF which was compiled with the Flex SDK that was the latest at the time of Flash Builder releases in the past. As the Flex framework is now donated to the Apache Foundation, the release cycles (and configurations) of Apache Flex SDK are not in schedule alignment with Flash Builder. Also, users of the Apache Flex SDK are free to make changes to the framework (as in any true open-source product).

So, we had no reliable way to keep the Design View in the product such that it would work with new Apache Flex SDKs (it may work, but we can't guarantee it).

As a result, like Ajay mentions above, we had to take the difficult decision to remove DV from the shipping product."

check this link on adobe community forum :
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1056583

Cheers

Comment: motherf...s killed a product.

Comment: they also say, lol. "While Adobe will ensure that the Adobe Flex SDK 4.6 and prior will be supported in future versions of Flash Player and AIR, it will be the responsibility of the Apache Flex Project to test future versions of the Apache Flex SDK against released Adobe runtimes to ensure compatibility and proper functioning."

Comment: also do a difficult decision to remove support of flex in flash player as well since there's no reliable way to keep the support in the player such that it would work with the new apache Flex SDK.